# Como modificar a margem em um ambiente minipage

Tags: latex

Galera, estou com um problema no meu código TeX, quero fazer um cabeçalho com uma imagem de cada lado, mas quero que essas imagens ocupem a parte da margem, ou seja, deixar a margem menor durante esse cabeçalho, mas não estou conseguindo. Segue a parte do código que quero editar a margem.

```
\begin{minipage}{1cm}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.08]{./imagens/Brasao_governo_MT.png}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{10cm}
   \centering
   {\ABNTEXchapterfont\normalsize\normalfont    \imprimirinstituicao}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{1cm}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.08]{./imagens/Brasao_Unemat.png}
\end{minipage}
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar fico muito agradecido.

*OBS 1:* Consegui fazer funcionar, mas eu tive que fazer com gambiarra usando o `\hspace*{}` se souberem de alguma forma mais "bonita" eu agradeço.